# What condition is being checked by the if statement

Tags: c++

So I'm looking up code in regards to 2D Haar Wavelet Transformation. And there's this if statement that I am confused about.

So part of the code looks like this:

```
unsigned char indexMask[4]; // the '4' here supposed to be a variable but I'm going to keep it simple here

for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
indexMask[k] = 0;
}

for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j+=2) {
    if (indexMask[j/2]) {
        //some codes here
    }
}
```

My confusion is, what does the if statement here checks? This is my first time seeing a if statement structured this way so I sort of confused. 
Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) (quoting only the relevent parts):

> ```
> if ( condition ) statement-true
>
> condition     -   expression which is contextually convertible to bool
> ```

In layman terms: Numbers can convert to `bool`. `0` is converted to `false` and everything else is converted to `true`.

Hence, the condition could also be written as

```
if (indexMask[j/2] != 0) {
    //some codes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

The *expression* `indexMask[j / 2]` is *implicitly convertible* to `true` or `false`. (It's an integral type, which will convert to `false` if 0 and `true` if any other value).

It's more readable than the hideous

```
if (indexMask[j / 2] == true)
```

or other unnecessarily long variants. Note also that if the initialisation was

```
unsigned char indexMask[4] = {};
```

then you wouldn't need that loop to set the elements to 0.

Comment: well, I'd say `if (indexMask[j / 2] != 0) `

Comment: @Moia or `if (indexMask[j / 2] != 0 ? true : false)` !

Comment: I was supposing to make the statement more clear

Comment: @Moia: It doesn't, not to me anyway.

Comment: Some people might cry with `cond ? true : false` instead of `cond`...

Comment: well you can always add more layers of confusion, what about `if (((indexMask[j / 2] == true) == true) == true)` ? :P

Comment: "operator" `!!` :) `!!indexMask[j / 2]`.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: You could probably get a lambda function in there somewhere too.

Comment: @Bathsheba my favourite tool for obfuscation still is the comma operator

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that `indexMask[j / 2]` is *contextually* converted into a boolean value. So basically every int or char value that is not 0 will be contextually be converted into `true`, while 0 will be converted into `false`.

Note that this is how C programmers use conditionals, as C does not have a boolean type, they use integers to return true / false values instead.

Also note that the conversion is not *implicit*, but is rather a contextual conversion, there is a large difference between them. But I would rather not explain them as it is most likely not inside the scope of this question.